# Visual Basic 2010 com ligação ao Access com imagens

Tags: vba, visual-basic-6

Bom dia, estou a realizar um projeto escolar em Visual Basic 2010 com a ligação a uma base de dados Access sobre Futebol.
Porém quero fazer algo mais complexo e incluir imagens nos jogadores, infelizmente estou com bastante dificuldade nisso, o tipo de dados que meti na Base de Dados é Objeto OLE
No Visual Basic tenho uma PictureBox com um OpenFileDialong com este código:

```
Try
  OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Abrir Imagem"
  OpenFileDialog1.FileName = "Imagens"
  OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files |*.*"
  OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
  ImgLigaPictureBox.Image = 
  System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Do nothing End Try
End Try
```

Este código permite buscar a imagem no computador, eu queria que agora que a imagem fosse guardada através de uma querie.
Não sei se isto é possível, se alguém poder ajudar.

Comment: Embora seja possível guardar imagens no banco de dados, na maioria dos casos o que se faz é salvar o arquivo em disco e gravar no banco apenas o caminho. Isso você saberia fazer?

Comment: Infelizmente não sei

Comment: Você quer algo do tipo `INSERT INTO Tabela1 (Imagem) VALUES (?)` ? Posso até criar o código para inserir images no registro, porém em Access não é recomendável fazer isso pois ele grava as linhas sequencialmente tornando-as grande e desalinhadas, assim fazendo com que as consultas se tornem cada vez mais lentas. Para Access a melhor abordagem é fazer igual ao op @bfavaretto mencionou, criar uma coluna do tipo `string` e salvar nessa coluna o caminho da imagem.

Comment: Outra abordagem é desistir do Access e usar um SGDB(MySQL, Oracle, SqlServer ou até mesmo o Firebird) pois o SGDB é organizado em fardos de dados fazendo com que a imagem não seja armazenada diretamente na linha e sim seja referenciada a uma porção dentro do próprio arquivo( dependendo do sistema um arquivo exterior).